# Calling "public webdriver"

Tags: c#, selenium

i have a problem. i use selenium with c#. i want to create only one webdriver.How can i calling webdriver another forms.

```
   public IWebDriver driver;
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.AddArgument(string.Format("user-data-dir={0}", @"C:\Users...."));



        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);


        string link = @"https://XXXXX";
```

Comment: Can you explain your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to create only one webdriver and, i want to calling all forms this webdriver.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the same WebDriver from other WinForms forms? Or are you talking about HTML forms?

Comment: yes, it winform.

Comment: You will either need to use a dependency injection framework to pass the IWebDriver object to new Form objects, or create a static class with a static method that returns the IWebDriver object. Something like WebDriverManager.GetWebDriver() or something. Then you can call this from the static context everyone in your application.